# Free audio recorder that mixes different audio sources (microphone, Discord, no other apps)

Tags: windows, gratis, podcast, audio-recording

I'm thinking about starting a podcast. This means that I need a voice recording app that records my microphone, doesn't record the sound from the speaker that gets into the microphone, but only specific applications such as Skype or Discord and not Windows sounds while I should be able to hear them on the speaker.

Does such a program for Windows exist? Preferably portable and not requiring administrator functions?

Comment: I doubt anything portable, non-admin exists.  However, http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm  has Virtual Audio Cable which allows you to combine any sound sources into a separate virtual channel which you can then use anything to record.  There is a free trial version for testing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to record output audio instead of microphone (basically speaking you asking How to Record the Sound Coming From Your PC)

This can all be done with software. No, you don’t even need to connect your computer’s audio output to its audio input with an audio cable to do this — although that is an option. Check this link out http://www.howtogeek.com/217348/how-to-record-the-sound-coming-from-your-pc-even-without-stereo-mix/ for more information on different FREE tools like Stereo Mix, Audacity, etc.

Hopefully this was helpful.

Comment: I want both Stereo Mix and the microphone, but also to filter the sound from the speaker that came into the microphone.